# How to get current user auto generated doc id from flutter firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get the current auto-generated user doc id to show and update data after login but getting a different id. Kindly help Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Hi @SyedRean, was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the document method on whichever collection you're trying to acquire a document from, and the returned result will include a getter for `documentID`.

```
final userDocument = usersCollection.document(); final documentID = userDocument.documentID;
```

When you initially want to create a document, you typically do this. I would include the documentID in the user document itself so that you can get it after you've produced it:

```
userDocument.setData({ documentID: documentID, /* ... */ });
```

document() Without specifying a route, this method will generate a random ID for you.
According to the documentation, an auto-generated ID is used if no [path] is specified. A client-generated date is prefixed to the unique key created to ensure that the resulting list is chronologically ordered.